# Enable CORS on Lumen API

Tags: ajax, laravel, lumen

I know it's a known issue but I've tried almost everything and I'm still stuck on this. I have a simple project structured like this:

```
                [Client]       =>     [Gateway]       =>      [API] 
                Laravel 6              Lumen 6               Lumen 6
             localhost:8000         localhost:8001       localhost:8002
```

> Since I'm just started working on this project only to prove if this works I've disabled all `auth` stuff.

On my **API** I have a folder within `public` called `uploads` (Basically in `http://localhost:8002/uploads/audio.amr`) where I have 1 audio file (.amr) and I'm trying to play it from a client view.

Since html can't play .amr files, I had to use a plugin. And I'm using this one [BenzAMRRecorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amr-js).

[Client side]
I make an ajax petition to get the url of the audio file. The **client** through guzzle connects with the **gateway** and the **gateway** also does it with the **API** and I successfully got the url `http://localhost:8002/uploads/audio.amr`.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     }
});

$.ajax({
     url : 'client/get_url_audio',
     type : 'GET',
     data : {
     },
     dataType:'json',
     success : function(data) {
         /** Here's the way to play the file */
         var amr = new BenzAMRRecorder();
         amr.initWithUrl(data['url']).then(function() {
            amr.play();
         });

     },

});
```

I successfully got the url but when the **BenzAMRRecorder** try to access to the url `http://localhost:8002/uploads/audio.amr` I got this error:

**The error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8002/uploads/audio.amr' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've read a lot of ways to fix this and I added a `CorsMiddleware` on the **API** with a handle function as follows:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    ];

    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
        return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }

    return $response;

}
```

And then on `bootstrap/app.php` added

```
$app->middleware([
      App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
]);
```

But I'm still getting the same error. The thing I thought is that, when the method `amr.initWithUrl(data['url'])` access to the API folder, it doesn't go to middleware and try to access **directly** to the folders without passing by the middleware but I don't know why. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

EDIT: I also tried with `github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors`

Comment: Is `uploads` a folder from  `/public` or a web route?

Comment: Yes, from `public`. Since I ran the command `php -S localhost:8000 -t ./public`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the `.htaccess` file from the server which holds the resource you are trying to access:

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: I just tried it and still not working. Even tried to putting it inside `<IfModule mod_headers.c>`

Comment: Try to add all headers from middleware to htaccess. Append them before lumen's directive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works in Lumen, but for Laravel, I've had a lot of success using this [neomerx/cors](https://github.com/neomerx/cors-psr7) package.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the header `X-CSRF-TOKEN` from your CORS middleware?

```
$headers = [
    ....

    // You will need to add ALL headers sent from your client
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-TOKEN'
];
```

Comment: Still not working. I gave up with this I'm trying to bring the audio file from the API and then save it on the client public folder and then the plugin will read the file locally and not from the API and I hope it'll works!